# iCalendar feed does not refresh in google calendar

Tags: icalendar

I made a feed that generates one single day event, always on todays date. This worksfine on Mac/iPad/iPhone. It moves every day to todays date. However in Google calendar the event remains on the date that the feed was imported and is never updated again.

This feed checks out fine on https://icalendar.org/validator.html
I have tried adding &nochache to the feed url
So far nothing helps.
My output:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:********
NAME:Develop testfeed
X-WR-CALNAME:Develop testfeed
DESCRIPTION:iCal feed
X-WR-CALDESC:iCal feed
REFRESH-INTERVAL;VALUE=DURATION:PT1H
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H
METHOD:PUBLISH
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
TIMEZONE-ID:Europe/Amsterdam
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Amsterdam
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20150421T141403
DTSTART:20231211T130000
DTEND:20231211T140000
SUMMARY:Titel
DESCRIPTION:eerste regel<br>tweede regel
UID:A1
LOCATION:Oudezijds Voorburgwal 141, Amsterdam
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Turns out I had to add SEQUENCE:$sequence
where $sequence is an integer that increments hourly from 0

In velocity I did it like this
#set($hours= $application.newDate().format("yyyyMMddHH"))
#set($sequence = $hours- 2023122009)